# Multiple Java web apps hosting in single hosting server & single public IP

Tags: tomcat, hosting, web-hosting, iis-8

I like to host 2 web apps with different domain, but sharing single public IP and server.

Currently, both are spring framework web application, is embedded Tomcat portable single run able war format JAVA application. (I can change to host via native Glassfish or Tomcat) Each web app using http & https - 2 listener ports...
It is possible sharing same public IP but handle request local by local port forwarding?

(1) Intercept request domain and forward to appropriate local port to handle, it is possible?

(2) I notice that >IIS8 have something call HttpPlatformHandler, not sure that support embedded Tomcat Java web app or not?

(3) Add another public IP?

Appreciate any guide please.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What you describe should be easily configurable by reading the configuration documentation for Tomcat.

Comment: Found solution. Since 2 tomcat running, can't share port for 80 & 443, So I just use port forwarding software listen on port 80 & 443, then forward every request according domain to those 2 web app in other local ports.

Comment: Smart Port Forwarding - Freeware can do what I want...